# OpenPrimaryTab fails with salesforce.com URL

Tags: consoleintegrationtoolkit

I'm trying to use the console integration in a visualforce page and just tested the URL 'https://www.salesforce.com' using the example from 'https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/api_console.pdf'.

It errors because it blocked a frame different then its origin. Both origins come from https://sandbox.salesforce.com so given an example and a copy and paste from that example, how does this not work?

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/41.0/integration.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, 'https://www.salesforce.com', false, 'salesforce', null, 'salesforcetab');
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Blocked a frame with origin "https://cs14.salesforce.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at Object.handleOnload (https://cs14.salesforce.com/support/console/xdomain/30.0/iframeinterface.js:1:357)
    at window.onload (https://cs14.salesforce.com/support/console/xdomain/30.0/crossDomainProxy.html:4:89)

Comment: Are you viewing this in classic and Lightning? Is there any error message in your javascript console?

looks more like CORS issue. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=extend_code_cors.htm&type=5

Comment: Classic view currently.

Comment: I had https://*.salesforce.com added to CORS but didn't change anything. I've tried with other URLS in the tab such as google and yahoo... all come back with the same error in the browser console "blocked a frame different then its origin" and yet doesn't matter what the URL is, its salesforce.com in each domain that apparently is of different origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`www.salesforce.com` has the header `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`. An origin is defined as the specific subdomain that exactly matches the origin. So, for example, in your sandbox, your origin is `cs14.salesforce.com`, while the domain for Salesforce is `www.salesforce.com`, and since `cs14.salesforce.com == www.salesforce.com` is false, the request for framing is blocked. You'll find that you can't frame basically any public salesforce.com page, because they'll all request the SAMEORIGIN request blocking. There's nothing you can do to make it work, because it is working as designed according to browser security.

You can use openPrimaryTab to show record pages, list views, Visualforce pages, and many other sites that do not have a prohibitive X-Frame-Options setting. Of course, this depends on the remote website's setting, as nothing you do in Salesforce will allow you to bypass the other site's configuration; it has to be configured on the website you're trying to display. You might try setting up a heroku app or something to see how that works in principle.

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: Seems like a bad example in their api documentation if its destined to fail.

Comment: @bl4kh4k Yeah, it *used* to work, maybe the Documentation Team didn't get the memo?